# jquery if div not id

Tags: jquery

I want to cut the price off to all input value in all divs, except only one `div sale_wrap`. how do I make an exception with jquery?

```
<div id="one_wrap">
  <input type="checkbox" name="1" value="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="1" value="">
</div>
<div id="two_wrap">
  <input type="checkbox" name="2" value="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="2" value="">
</div>
<div id="sale_wrap">
  <input type="checkbox" name="3" value="">
</div>
```

jquery:

```
if($("div").attr("id") != "sale_wrap") {
  t_balance;
} else {
  var sale = t_balance*((100-window.discount_p)/100);
  t_balance = sale;
}
```

Comment: Something going wrong here. `$("div").attr("id")` always return id of first div from selected. I hope, that condition will be always true. Could you tell us in which function/event, you trying this code.?

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to do here. The HTML markup is all checkboxes, and your example JS (pseudo-code?) is setting some global 't_balance' based on some other global 'discount_p'... it seems as if your JS code may be part of some function that is already looping through the divs, and returning 't_balance'?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use [not selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
$("div:not(#sale_wrap)")
```

Comment: The '.att("id") != "sale_wrap"', and the whole 'if' statement, is redundant. The not selector has already removed the 'sale_wrap' id from the result set, so there's no need to check for it again.

Comment: oh thanx. didnt read the code completely. modified answer. The example in the question does look weird the attr('id') in the if will return id of first element only.

Comment: agreed, it isn't very clear what the OP is actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 12):

The jQuery [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) function can do this.

To select all div's except the div with `id` of `sale_wrap`:

```
$('div').not('#sale_wrap')
```

You can then loop over the divs with `each()`.

As an example:

```
#HTML
<p id="1">Some text in paragraph 1</p>
<p id="2">Some text in paragraph 2</p>
<p id="3">Some text in paragraph 3</p>

#JS
# turn background to blue for all 'p' except p with id=2
$('p').not('#2').each(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
});
```

Check out [this example on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WUzNs/).

Comment: If you need a native DOM NodeList from this then call `var nodeList = $('div').not('#sale_wrap').get();`

Answer (score 3):

Try using

```
if($('div').not('#sale_wrap'))
{
  t_balance;
} 
else
{
  var sale = t_balance*((100-window.discount_p)/100);
  t_balance = sale;
}
```

Comment: '$('div').not('#sale_wrap')' will return a jQuery element containing all 'div' elements that do not have an id of 'sale_wrap'. It's not a conditional check for a specific div, so there's no need for an 'if' statement. This 'if' statement will always eval to 'true' if there is any div in the markup with an id other than 'sale_wrap'

Answer (score 2):

Just to add little more information.
One can use multiple [not selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) like this:

```
$("div:not(#sale_wrap):not(.sale_class)");
```

or

```
$("div:not(#sale_wrap, .sale_class)");
```

or

```
$("div").not('#sale_wrap, .sale_class');
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
$('div[id != "sale_wrap"]')
```