# jQuery: how to exclude IDs from .find()?

Tags: jquery, validation, input, find

**I have this code:**

```
$("#someform").find("input:not[#myid]").change(function() {
....
});
```

But the code is not working.

*The task:*
I need to select **all** the inputs, but exclude one with `ID="myid"`.

Your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery if div not id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804009/jquery-if-div-not-id)

Comment: @yvesmancera possible not....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close, use parenthesis instead of square brackets

```
$("#someform").find("input:not(#myid)").change(function() {
....
});
```

See [**:not()**](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

Syntax of **[`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)** is not correct ,

```
$("#someform").find("input:not(#myid)").change(function() {
   //                       --^-- --^--
   ....
});
```

Or you can use **[`not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/)**

```
$("#someform").find("input").not("#myid").change(function() {
   ....
});
```