# Trying to hide an element with id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to know if this is possible:

I have an element with an id but I'd like to know if I can hidde other elements which they do not have that id

I mean:

```
<div id="tag1">
 Hi 1
</div>

<div id="tag2">
 Hi 2
</div>
```

.... to N elements

```
<div id="tagN">
 Hi N
</div>


$(document).ready(function(){
  ?????
});
```

How can I show tag1 and hide tag2 to tagN elements?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery if div not id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804009/jquery-if-div-not-id)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector:

```js
$('div[id^="tag"]').not("#tag1").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tag1">
 Hi 1
</div>

<div id="tag2">
 Hi 2
</div>

<div id="tag3">
 Hi 3
</div>
```

But your code will have more performance if you add a class for all elements instead of selecting by attribute, like I did above. E.g.:

```
$("div.tag").not("#tag1").hide();
```

Comment: Plus 1 for the class addition and performance considerations.